# How Bind DataTable to DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatable

This is my DataTable.

```
DataTable _simpleDataTable = new ataTable();     

var person = new DataColumn("Person") {DataType = typeof (Person)};
_simpleDataTable.Columns.Add(person);

var student = new DataColumn("Student") {DataType = typeof (Student)};
_simpleDataTable.Columns.Add(student);

 var dr1 = _simpleDataTable.NewRow();
dr1[0] = new Person {PersonId = 1, PersonName = "TONY"};
dr1[1] = new Student { StudentId = 1, StudentName = "TONY" };
_simpleDataTable.Rows.Add(dr1);

var dr2 = _simpleDataTable.NewRow();
dr2[0] = new Person { PersonId = 2, PersonName = "MAL" };
dr2[1] = new Student { StudentId = 2, StudentName = "MAL" };
_simpleDataTable.Rows.Add(dr2);
```

Plaase tell me how to bind above type of DataTable.

Comment: @SLaks `_simpleDataTable` to an `DataGrid` to display the data

Answer (score 8):

**This is a working sample solution based on the requirements in the question and [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677446/binding-wpf-datagrid-to-datatable-using-templatecolumns)**

### MainWindow

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="HowBindDataTableToDataGrid.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- you need foreach class one DataTemplate-->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="PersonDataTemplate" DataType="Person">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Background="LightBlue" Text="{Binding PersonId}"/>
                <TextBlock Background="AliceBlue" Text="{Binding PersonName}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="StudentDataTemplate" DataType="Student">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Background="Orange" Text="{Binding StudentId}"/>
                <TextBlock Background="Yellow" Text="{Binding StudentName}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="simpleDataGrid" AutoGeneratingColumn="simpleDataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**.CS**

```
using System.Data;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace HowBindDataTableToDataGrid
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            simpleDataGrid.ItemsSource = LoadDataTable().AsDataView();
        }

        private void simpleDataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyType == typeof(Person))
            {
                MyDataGridTemplateColumn col = new MyDataGridTemplateColumn();
                col.ColumnName = e.PropertyName;
                col.CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)FindResource("PersonDataTemplate");
                e.Column = col;
                e.Column.Header = e.PropertyName;
            }
            else if (e.PropertyType == typeof(Student))
            {
                MyDataGridTemplateColumn col = new MyDataGridTemplateColumn();
                col.ColumnName = e.PropertyName;
                col.CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)FindResource("StudentDataTemplate");
                e.Column = col;
                e.Column.Header = e.PropertyName;
            }
        }

        private DataTable LoadDataTable()
        {
            var _simpleDataTable = new DataTable();

            var person = new DataColumn("Person") { DataType = typeof(Person) };
            _simpleDataTable.Columns.Add(person);

            var student = new DataColumn("Student") { DataType = typeof(Student) };
            _simpleDataTable.Columns.Add(student);

            var dr1 = _simpleDataTable.NewRow();
            dr1[0] = new Person { PersonId = 1, PersonName = "TONY" };
            dr1[1] = new Student { StudentId = 1, StudentName = "TONY" };
            _simpleDataTable.Rows.Add(dr1);

            var dr2 = _simpleDataTable.NewRow();
            dr2[0] = new Person { PersonId = 2, PersonName = "MAL" };
            dr2[1] = new Student { StudentId = 2, StudentName = "MAL" };
            _simpleDataTable.Rows.Add(dr2);

            return _simpleDataTable;
        }
    }

    public class MyDataGridTemplateColumn : DataGridTemplateColumn
    {
        public string ColumnName { get; set; }

        protected override System.Windows.FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
        {
            // The DataGridTemplateColumn uses ContentPresenter with your DataTemplate.
            ContentPresenter cp = (ContentPresenter)base.GenerateElement(cell, dataItem);
            // Reset the Binding to the specific column. The default binding is to the DataRowView.
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(cp, ContentPresenter.ContentProperty, new Binding(this.ColumnName));
            return cp;
        }
    }
}
```

### Person.cs

```
namespace HowBindDataTableToDataGrid
{
    public class Person
    {
        private int personId;
        private string personName;

        public int PersonId
        {
            get { return personId; }
            set { personId = value; }
        }
        public string PersonName
        {
            get { return personName; }
            set { personName = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

### Student.cs

```
namespace HowBindDataTableToDataGrid
{
    public class Student
    {
        private int personId;
        private string personName;

        public int StudentId 
        {
            get { return personId; }
            set { personId = value; }
        }
        public string StudentName 
        {
            get { return personName; }
            set { personName = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DataGrid.ItemsSource = DataTable.AsDataView();
```

or in other words you can do

```
yourDataGridInstance.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
yourDataGridInstance.ItemsSource = _simpleDataTable.AsDataView();
```

Comment: -1 this solution works only for simple Datatypes. He needs something with an `DataTemplate`

Answer (score 3):

A solution for non-WPF DataGrid:

```
//Create DataTable

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

//Put some columns in it.

dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Item #", typeof(int)));

dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Contract Number", typeof(string)));

dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Customer Name", typeof(string)));

// Create the record

DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

dr["Item #"] = i;

dr["Customer Name"] = xmn2[1].InnerText;  //value from textbox on screen

dr["Contract Number"] = xmn4[1].InnerText; //value from textbox on screen

dt.Rows.Add(dr);

//Bind the GridView to the data in the data table for display.

this.GridView1.Visible = true;

GridView1.DataSource = dt;

GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: This solution is for normal datagrid and not for WPF datagrid.

Comment: -1 this solution works only for simple Datatypes. He needs something with an DataTemplate

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
DataTable _simpleDataTable = new ataTable();
DataGridInstance.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
DataGridInstance.ItemsSource = _simpleDataTable.DefaultView;
```

Comment: -1 this solution works only for simple Datatypes. He needs something with an `DataTemplate`