# Working with Datatable and dataGridView

Tags: c#, ado.net

1. From Datatable to dataGridView using filter.
   I have Datatable, how to insert data from this Datatable to dataGridView, where column value must be equivalent to specific value.

Like SQL-command:
select * from testTable
where name = 'test'

1. Changing values in dataGridView
   I want to select some rows in dataGridView and by clicking a button, change value in columns of selected rows. And then changes from dataGridView must apply to Datatable (dataGridView source).
2. Count From Datatable using filter.

How can I count rows from Datatable, where column value must be equivalent to specific value.

Like SQL-command:
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM Ticket
Where name = 'test'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tUse `DataAdapter` to Fill Data in a `DataSet`,Use it as Source for DataGridView,Afer you have made changes just call .update();

```
public SqlDataAdapter sda { get; set; }
public DataSet ds { get; set; }    
public Form2()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from testTable where name = 'test'",connection_string);
            ds=new DataSet();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
    }
    private void Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sda.Update(ds);
    }
```

For Changing Value of columns of multiple column on Button Click

```
private void Change_ColumnValue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow  row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
            {
                ds.Tables[0].Rows[row.Index]["Column_Name"] = row.Cells["Column_Name"].Value;
            }
    }
```

For Counting Rows using a Filer use Following Code

```
ds.Tables[0].Select("Column_Name='value'").Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to bind the datatable to the datagridview.

Just have a look at the following liks:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/fbk67b6z(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/fbk67b6z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

or at stackoverflow...

[how to bind datatable to datagridview in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114635/how-to-bind-datatable-to-datagridview-in-c-sharp)

[How Bind DataTable to DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808210/how-bind-datatable-to-datagrid)