# Edits to dynamic DataTable not updating in DataGrid

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, datatable

I have a DataTable and when I alter (add,modifiy..ect) it wont reflect on the DataGrid which is bound to the DataTable.

```
ItemsSource="{Binding TableData,Mode=TwoWay,IsAsync=True}"
```

Thats the binding ^

Now when I set the RowError

```
TableData.Rows[x].RowError = ex.Message;
```

HasError gets set to true... but the DataGrid does not reflect this ( I have a style that marks a row red when there is an error)

Note: My changes are not being reflected on more then setting ErrorMessages, I've also tried adding rows in the ViewModel and those added rows are not relfected either.

About the DataTable:
It has no set columns or anything, it relfects a selected Database table which the user picks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding to a `DataTable` won't work.  You need to first convert your `DataTable` to an `ObservableCollection<>`.  From [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/94238dc4-00c4-4af4-afb9-195f89ece621/):

```
    public void ConvertDataTable( DataTable dt )
    {
        DataList  = new ObservableCollection<ProjectWorkHours>();
        //Scan and arrange data into ObservableCollection
        int UserID = 0;
        if ( dt.Rows.Count >0 )
        {
            UserID = int.Parse( dt.Rows[0]["UserID"].ToString() );
            //Distill project id list
            List<int> ProjectIDList = GetProjectIDList( dt );
            for ( int i = 0 ; i < ProjectIDList.Count; i ++ )
            {
                int ProjectID= ProjectIDList[i];
                //Get WorkRecord
                int[] MyWorkRecord = GetWorkRecord(dt, ProjectID);
                ProjectWorkHours newProjectWorkHours = new ProjectWorkHours(UserID,ProjectID,MyWorkRecord);
                DataList.Add( newProjectWorkHours);
            }           
        } 
    }
```

The link has a more full example of working with a database and using binding.

Comment: Thanks, that will have to do.

Comment: Another possiblility is here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677446/binding-wpf-datagrid-to-datatable-using-templatecolumns

Answer (score 0):

What Type is TableData?

If it is a `List<>` then changing the items in the list will **NOT** update the binding
If it is an `ObservableCollection<>` then changing the items in the collection will update the binding

Comment: Its a DataTable (  public DataTable TableData)

Comment: No its a TableDate! Look at the variable your binding with the itemsource. I'm asking what Type is the variable.