# Populate DataTable with Datagrid data in WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datatable

I want to store the data of a datagrid in a datatable. How can I populate the datatable with that data?

Need a way to access data in a row and column format rather than a item format. So, a solution for the same is welcomed and needed asap.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677446/binding-wpf-datagrid-to-datatable-using-templatecolumns

Comment: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/thread4698-how-to-bind-the-data-in-gridview.aspx

Comment: http://wpf-4-0.blogspot.ie/2012/12/how-to-bind-datatable-in-dataset-to-wpf.html

Comment: Thanks Rachel.. Post your first comment as answer to accept it..

Comment: Link only answers are not acceptable answers. You can vote up one of my other answers. See my profile. Thanks.

Comment: Ok.
Can I create a datatable from ICollectionView??

Answer (score 0):

To your second question, I think you can.

Try this

```
 DataView myView = new DataView( MyDataTable ); 
 ICollectionView cv = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myView);
```

Hopefully helpful

Rachel

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253725/convert-ienumerable-to-datatable