# Data not displaying in datagrid

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

Here is my code.
XAML :

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding }" Height="200" Name="dataGrid1" Width="200" />
```

cs :

```
SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Server=(local);Database=Sample_db;Trusted_Connection=Yes;");
thisConnection.Open();    
string Get_Data = "SELECT * FROM emp";  
SqlCommand cmd = thisConnection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = Get_Data;
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);               
DataTable dt = new DataTable("emp");
sda.Fill(dt);
// MessageBox.Show(cmd.CommandText);
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

It displays line on grid.Not the actual data.Kindly help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: does your `dt` contains some rows?

Comment: @WiiMaxx I have 3 rows in my table and properly showing in SQL Server.

Comment: ahh silly me just remove `ItemsSource="{Binding }"`

Comment: @WiiMaxx i removed it,But no effect,same result.

Comment: mhh on which part do you set the information in the loading part or in the construtor?

Comment: Try with AutoGenerateColumns="True"

Comment: @jure thanks , AutoGenerateColumns="True" works.

Comment: @jure :D that should be an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you using ItemSource you have to generate an ItemTemplate.
[Binding WPF DataGrid to DataTable using TemplateColumns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677446/binding-wpf-datagrid-to-datatable-using-templatecolumns)

Using instead DataContext:

```
SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Server=(local);Database=Sample_db;Trusted_Connection=Yes;");
                thisConnection.Open();    
                string Get_Data = "SELECT * FROM emp";  
                SqlCommand cmd = thisConnection.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = Get_Data;
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);               
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("emp");
                sda.Fill(dt);
               // Here:                
               dataGrid1.DataContext = dt.DefaultView;
```

DataContext is a general (dependency) property of all descendants of FrameworkElement. Is is inherited through the logical tree from parent to children and can be used as an implicit source for DataBinding. It does not do anything by itself, you must basically databind to it.

ItemsSource is the property identifying the source for templated generation of items in an ItemsControl derived control (or HierarchicalDataTemplate).

Answer (score 2):

`Datatable` **will not** generate datagrid rows with `AutoGenerateColumns="False"`.

Please change it to `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` or add your own data columns in `<Datagrid.Columns>` property.